# Problem about x86-based Microsoft C++ Build Tools

Tags: visual-c++, x86, 32bit-64bit, 32-bit

During importing in the Jupyter Notebook I faced a problem regarding Microsoft Visual C++ ( error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/)

I am working with a system based on windows 7 - 32 bit. But I can not find a download link with these properties (x86-based Microsoft C++ Build Tools). I would appreciate it if you help me in this regard. Thank you.

Comment: The Visual Built Tools for Visual Studio 2013 (admittedly a very lame naming convention, it' actually the Microsoft Build Tools 2014 (x86) package) and can be downloaded from your my.visualstudio.com/downloads.